# Regional Ashkenazi Pronunciation

Tags: hebrew, pronunciation, ashkenazi

I don't know if this is the right forum to ask this, but I would like to find audio tracks of Jews from different Ashkenazi communities speaking Hebrew (be they leyning, davening, discoursing or merely incorporating Hebrew words into their regular speech). Rav Nissan Kaplan's [shiurim](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/) provide many examples of an Israeli Litvak pronunciation, but I would like to hear other pronunciations as well. Specifically, I would most like Hungarian and Galizianer, but the more the better.

Apologies if this is off-topic.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/what-is-our-attitude-to-list-questions?answertab=votes

Comment: Piyut.co.il has a lot of recordings of piyyutim in different pronunciations of Hebrew, including many Ashkenazi types.

Comment: If still interested, here's a Hungarian Jew with a very strong Galizianer accent: http://ledorvador.hu/extra-16-resz/